# Using Library inspect to list functions in a package

Tags: python-3.5, inspect

I am trying to get the list of functions in a package.
The package contains some internal functions that I would like to exclude.

For example this is how my package looks

```
def _test():
    pass

def printNames():
    pass

def returnSum():
    pass
```

What I am trying to do is get the members as a list: `[printNames, returnSum]`

Code:

```
inspect.getmembers(package, inspect.isfunction)
```

What this returns to me instead is `[printNames, returnSum, _test]`

All internal functions start with an underscore '_'.
How can I exclude such functions?

Comment: What about filtering the list: `filter(lambda name: not name.startswith('_'), members)`

Comment: I did think of doing something similar and removing elements in the list that start with a '_' but was wondering if there was a built in functionality in inspect. But thanks for the idea with filter